What is the square root of a square matrix squared?
Admittedly, made the title a little funny, but this is a valid question.
I have come across the following equation
$$
I x^2=AA
$$
where $I$ is a unit matrix, $A$ is a square matrix of the same dimension and x is just a number. Can I conclude that $I x=A$?

How is square root defined in your case?

$A$ is certainly one valid root under any reasonable interpretation.

we diagonalize the matrix, then take the square root of the each element. I know how to do it by  brute force,  but I was wondering if there are any identities.

If $B$ is positive-semidefinite, $\sqrt B$ is the unique positive semi-definite matrix $C$ such that $C^2=B$ (see Square root of a matrix on Wikipedia.) In your case, you need $A$ to be self-adjoint to apply this definition.

$AA$ is not always diagonalizable, e.g. for $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

for the sake of the argument, let's say it is diagonalizable.

The issue is that matrices can have infinitely many square roots, or indeed none at all. For example, if you begin with a matrix $A$ representing any reflection in any line in $\Bbb{R}^2$, then $A^2 = I$. Which of these $A$ is the square root? Who's to say. Just a user's comment points to a canonical choice for positive-semidefinite $B$, but in general, there is no canonical choice, and in some circumstances, there's no choice at all.

You already can't conclude this for ordinary real or complex numbers; the best you could possibly ask for is that $A = \pm x$ (by which I mean $A = \pm x$ times the identity matrix).
But actually you can't even expect this. $A$ can be any diagonalizable matrix whose eigenvalues are $\pm \sqrt{x}$; even if we restrict only to diagonal matrices there are $2^n$ square roots (if $x \neq 0$), and without that restriction there are uncountably many square roots.
Worse, if $x = 0$ then $A$ need not be diagonalizable at all.
